# How do I get information after a certain sentence in a txt file?

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file regarding different information about Ip addresses after a test has been completed. I want to print out this information, how?

The text file is called "IPAddressesTEST.log"

a part of the text follows like this

Connected IPv6's:

(and here is the ipv6 address)

I've tried:

```py
with open ('C:/test/IPAddressesTEST.log', "rt") as Ip_Log:
    for l in Ip_Log:
        Ip_Log_Iter = iter(l)
        for lines in Ip_Log_Iter:
            if lines == "Connected IPv6's:":
                x = next(Ip_Log_Iter)
                break
print(x)
```

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more information: Do you want to fetch everything after the `Connecetd IPv6's` line, or just the line immediately after it? Is there only one instance of `Connecetd IPv6's`, or are there multiple? I'd also like to see what you've tried so far

Comment: I only want the information right after Connected IPv6's: and there are no other instances of it before that one. I've tried something like this -
 with open ('C:/test/IPAddressesTEST.log', "rt") as Ip_Log:

        for l in Ip_Log:
            Ip_Log_Iter = iter(l)
        for lines in Ip_Log_Iter:
            if lines == "Connected IPv6's:":
                lines = next(Ip_Log_Iter)
                break
           print (lines)

Comment: @Icewolf Could you please add the code that you've tried to the question?

Comment: I know it's bad code but I'm very new to python so I'm sorry @Vitalizzare

Comment: I know realize that when doing the 
   Ip_Log_Iter = iter(l)
that it will not work.
I basically tried to make a copy of the file into an iterator so I could use the "next" function and only get the ip after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the "IPAddressesTEST.log" looks like this:

```text
junk 
stuff
Connected IPv6's:
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5
foo
bar
Connected IPv6's:
2392:0411:2CB2:0000:0000:0567:5226:24ba
more stuff
more junk
```

Then the following will print out the lines immediately following a line containing the string "Connected IPv6's:"

```py
with open('IPAddressesTEST.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for counter, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "Connected IPv6's:" in line:
        print(lines[counter +1].strip())
```

Output:

```text
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5
2392:0411:2CB2:0000:0000:0567:5226:24ba
```

---

**Edit**

As requested, if you only want the first instance of `Connected IPv6's` then you don't need to keep looping through the file so can `break` as soon as the relevant line is found:

```py
with open('IPAddressesTEST.log', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for counter, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "Connected IPv6's:" in line:
        print(lines[counter +1].strip())
        break
```

Output:

```text
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5
```

Notice it's just the IP address closest to the top of the file

Comment: If anyone con help me stop the syntax highlighting for my plain text blocks, that would be appreciated

Comment: How would I only get the fist output? @PangolinPaws

Comment: If you're only interested in the first instance of `Connected IPv6's` in the file then you don't need the `for` loop. Just omit the line beginning `for counter, line...` and un-indent both lines below by 1 tab.

Comment: how much of the beginning should I remove in the for loop? I only get errors whatever I do, I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern = "(?<=Connected IPv6's:\n)\S*"
text = "Connected IPv6's:\n2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5"
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

output:

> ['2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5']